# Custom view xml versus its usage

Tags: android, xml, android-custom-view

I have a custom view `CustomSettingEntry` this is its xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_custom_setting_entry_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/custom_setting_entry_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then I use it in a fragment and assign it an id:

```
<com.mypackage.name.CustomSettingEntry
                android:id="@+id/layout_notification_setting"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:setting_title="@string/title"
                app:setting_subtitle="@string/subtitle" />
```

My question is what's the difference between the LinearLayout with id `layout_custom_setting_entry_container` and the usage with id `layout_notification_setting`? do they refer to the same thing?

If I set a click listener on the custom view inside the fragment, then later in some condition disabled clicking on the root LinearLayout inside the custom view, will this stop the listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your custom view is a subclass of `LinearLayout` which inflates an xml layout. If so, the resulting view hierarchy is

```
[LinearLayout (actually a CustomSettingEntry), id : layout_notification_setting]
    [LinearLayout, id : layout_custom_setting_entry_container]
        ...
```

So there are two levels of viewgroups, each one with it own id.

By the way this is inefficient because, the outer viewgroup (your custom class) has only one child (the root of the xml).

On solution is to use a `<merge>` as root of the xml layout to skip one level. See [Optimize by merging](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html)  or [Inflating layout for your custom view](http://trickyandroid.com/protip-inflating-layout-for-your-custom-view/)
 for more details.

Comment: Yes it's a subclass of `LinearLayout`.

So if i used `<merge>` as root layout, when i use `this` keyword inside my custom view class, it would refer to the LinearLayout of the usage? in this case with id `layout_notification_setting`?

Comment: yes. Actually in both case `this` has the id `layout_notification_setting`. Using `<merge>` only avoid the creation of the `LinearLayout` withe the id `layout_custom_setting_entry_container` (useless because `CustomSettingEntry` is also a `LinearLayout`)